# Custom Losss Function Tensorflow datatype error

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, arcface

I am trying implement a custom arcface loss function:

```py
def call(self, y_true: FloatTensor, y_pred: FloatTensor) -> FloatTensor:
    projector = tf.math.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=1)
    predictor = tf.math.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=1)
    cos_theta = tf.matmul(projector, predictor)
    cos_theta = tf.clip_by_value(cos_theta, -1.0, 1.0)
    index = tf.where(self.num_classes != -1)[0]
    m_hot = tf.zeros(index.size()[0], cos_theta.size()[1])
    m_hot.scatter_(1, self.num_classes[index, None], self.margin)
    cos_theta = tf.acos(cos_theta)
    cos_theta[index] += m_hot
    cos_theta = cos_theta.cos()
    cos_theta = tf.math.multiply(cos_theta, self.scale)
    loss: FloatTensor = tf.nn.softmax(cos_theta, dim=1)
    return loss
```

But am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Expected uint8 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Maximum', got 1e-12 of type 'float' instead. Error: Expected uint8, but got 1e-12 of type 'float'.

Comment: which line is it?

Comment: projector = tf.math.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=1), first line